# SQL Query: Select a query to join 3 table With case Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, case

I have a db with 3 tables in it.

They have below structures:

`Table1:`
YearandMonth, EmployeeID, CodepayID, Currentvalue, Backvalue

`Table2:`
CodePayID, Description, SysType, PayType, LoanInd

`Table3:`
YearandMonth, EmployeeID, CodePayid, missType, Value1, Value2, Value3

Now, I need a select query to result in the following conclusion:

`EmpID |  Description | Value 2 | Sum (abs(CurrentValue)+ABS(Backvalue))| SummyColumn`

is case item:

```
Case 1: if LoanInd =4 ,SummyColumn = value1 from table3
eles SummyColumn = Value3 from table3
```

`Conditions:`

```
PayType = 0 AND YearandMonth=202106
Group by EmployeeID, CodepayID
```

`Comments:`

```
Select a.EmployeeID, b.Description, c.Value2 as tempItem, Sum (abs(CurrentValue)+ABS(Backvalue)) as SecSum, SummyColumn
From [Table1] a, [Table2] b, [Table3] c
Where b.PayType=0 AND a.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID and a.YearandMonth = c.YearandMonth AND a.CodePayID = b.CodePayID AND b.CodePayID = c.CodePayID AND a.YearMonth = 202106
Group by a.EmployeeID, a.CodePayID
```

**Update:**
I Change my Query to the below :

```
SELECT a.[EmployeeID]
      ,b.[Description]
      ,(Case When a.[codepayId] >= 500 AND a.[codepayId]<= 800 Then SUM(abs(c.[Value2])) Else SUM(abs(a.[CurrentValue]) + abs(a.[Backvalue]))End) as SUMVal
      ,(Case When b.[LoanInd] = 4 Then c.[Value1] Else c.[Value3] End) as myVal2

  FROM [Table1] as a 
    Left JOIN [Table2] as b
    ON a.[CodePayID] = b.[CodePayID]
    Left JOIN [Table3] as c 
    ON c.[EmployeeID] = a.[EmployeeID] AND c.[YearandMonth] = a.[YearandMonth] AND b.[CodePayID] = c.[CodePayID]
where b.[PayType]=0 AND a.[YearandMonth]=202106
```

It`s Error with this message:

`Column 'Table1.EmployeeID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: What is your question here? Also, it's 2021, it's *long* past you stopped using that 32 year old syntax and updated to the newer 29 year old explicit join syntax.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: have you tried the simple case expression ? ```case when LoanInd =4 then value 1 else value 3 end as SummyColumn```

Comment: @linusRian, case _expression_.

Comment: @Larnu, It is my Question: How achieve to the slected result? `EmpID |  Description | Value 2 | Sum (abs(CurrentValue)+ABS(Backvalue))| SummyColumn`. I have not any experience with join syntax

Comment: Select those columns, and group by the one's that aren't aggregated, @TheAlien . Like any other aggregate query. If you're unfamiliar with `SUM` have a read of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15); it comes with plenty of [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples).

Comment: @Larnu, When I try joins 2 table with left join, that seems ok, Count rows of result is [9057] but when joins 3rd table, the row of result increase to 9302?! Any suggestion?

Comment: The `JOIN` is changing the number of rows, @TheAlien . This is normal, and expected, behaviour.

Comment: @linusRian, Thanks, the case expression it`s ok,